# Translation - "form" (internet form you fill out, NOT an application)

Tags: translation

A translation question for ya :)
I'm in need of the word for "form". In this case it is a form on a webpage a user fills out to answer survey questions ("how did you think you did? did you enjoy it?").
We have a form generator - we can make many forms like these to present to the user. But I am unsure as to which word to use.

My candidates are:
フォーム (easy!)

態 e.g. 事業態

書類 (document)

Which is correct for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing an アンケート.  This is from French *enquête*, and I think it's usually translated into English as 'questionnaire' or 'survey'.

If you mean a technical term for the actual HTML `<form>` element, then I think that would just be フォーム like you said.

Comment: No not the technical term (but nice that you considered that).
Yes a questionnaire! Would アンケート work then?

Comment: Yes, we say for example [Googleフォーム](https://www.google.com/intl/ja_jp/forms/about/)でアンケートを作ろう!